# Write a shell script that replaces multiple strings in multiple files

Tags: macos, shell, sed, terminal

I need to search through many files in a directory for a list of keywords and add a prefix to all of them. For example, if various files in my directory contained the terms **foo**, **bar**, and **baz**, I would need to change all instances of these terms to: **prefix_foo**, **prefix_bar**, and **prefix_baz**.

I'd like to write a shell script to do this so I can avoid doing the search one keyword at a time in SublimeText (there are a lot of them). Unfortunately, my shell-fu is not that strong.

So far, following [this](http://www.linuxask.com/questions/replace-multiple-strings-using-sed) advice, I have created a file called "replace.sed" with all of the terms formatted like this:

s/foo/prefix_foo/g
s/bar/prefix_bar/g
s/baz/prefix_baz/g

The terminal command it suggests to use with this list is:

```
sed -f replace.sed < old.txt > new.txt
```

I was able to adapt this to replace instances within the file (instead of creating a new file) by setting up the following script, which I called inline.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
in=${1?No input file specified}
mv $in ${bak=.$in.bak}
shift
"$@" < $bak > $in
```

Putting it all together, I ended up with this command:

```
~/inline.sh old.txt sed -f replace.sed
```

I tried this and it works, for one file at a time. How would I adapt this to search and replace through all of the files in my entire directory?

Comment: Run your script through http://shellcheck.net/ and fix the issues it flags -- my answer is safe against filenames with spaces and such on its own, but your `inline.sh` currently is _not_ safe in that same respect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for f in *; do
  [[ -f "$f" ]] && ~/inline.sh "$f" sed -f ~/replace.sed
done
```

Comment: Now, how would I make this recursive?

Comment: @unifactor, what version of bash? If 4.0 or newer, `shopt -s globstar` and then use `for f in **/*`.

Comment: ...if older than that, then `find . -type f -exec ~/inline.sh '{}' sed -f ~/replace.sed ';'`

Answer (score 1):

In a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
files=`ls -1 your_directory | egrep keyword`

for i in ${files[@]}; do
    cp ${i} prefix_${i}
done
```

This will, of course, leave the originals where they are.

Comment: ...also, you're using array syntax at expansion time (incorrectly, given lack of quotes), but you aren't actually defining `files` as an array (which is why _adding_ quotes without fixing the way `files` is defined to actually be an array will break things).

Comment: `files=( your_directory/*keyword* )` would be the array-assignment equivalent, btw, thereafter `for i in "${files[@]}"; do cp "$i" "prefix_$i"; done`. The curly braces in `${i}` don't have any impact on correctness here -- one can take them or leave them in this particular use case -- but the lack of quotes is actually harmful for filenames that can also be intepreted as glob expressions or which contain characters in IFS.